# Spring Cache - How can i get list of all actual data entities after changing in other cache-methods with custom key?

Tags: java, spring, caching

I have crud methods that modify the data in the cache and database
I also have a method that returns all entities when I use it after changes in the cache and database, I get irrelevant data.
As I understand it, the point is in the method of returning all entities. It uses the default key, it is different from other methods.
What do I need to do so that I can return the actual data sheet?

```
@Service
@CacheConfig(cacheNames = "configuration")
class ServiceConfiguration{

 @Cacheable //this method returns non actual data
    public List<MySomeConfiguration> getAllProxyConfigurations() {
        return repository.getAllConfigurations();
}

   @Cacheable(key = "#root.target.getConfigurationById(#id).serverId")
    public MySomeConfiguration getConfigurationById(Long id) {
...
   return configuration;
}

 @CachePut(key = "#configuration.serverId", condition = "#result.id != null")
    public MySomeConfiguration addOrUpdateConfiguration(Configuration configuration) {
   return configuration;
}

   @Cacheable(key = "#serverId")
    public MySomeConfiguration getConfigurationByServerId(String serverId) {...
   return configuration;
}

   @CacheEvict(key = "#root.target.getConfigurationById(#id).serverId")
    public void deleteConfigurationById(Long id) {
...
}
}//end class
```

p.s. sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

By default redis cache manager uses StringRedisSerializer for Key serializer

Your class toString() is used to serializer the key of the object so don't give different keys for different methods like put, get, evict etc  jus rely on your toString() to get the key or override by using Spring Cache Custom KeyGenerator

Refer

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cache-custom-keygenerator

Comment: "By default redis cache manager uses StringRedisSerializer for Key serializer"
i can't use redis. 
So what do I need to do?

Comment: What is your cache backend? I assumed it is redis ..the bottom line is that the key has to be consistent

Comment: spring cache is an abstraction and we need a cache backend to store the actual data like redis , ConcurrentMap ,ehcache etc ..which one are you using . Refer https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html